# How to detect a paper in real time in android

Tags: android, opencv

I am currently using [Android Scanner](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo) which detects the edges of a paper if it is found in a picture, how do I achieve the same thing in real time? Is there a similar library available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this great application, exactly fits my needs, just posting it here if someone else out there is looking for the same thing.

https://github.com/ctodobom/OpenNoteScanner